# Adding texture to blender

Tags: modeling, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

[image]

Hi, guys. I m trying to add this image of a lens to the faces I selected in UV mode but didn't get how to do this. It is a model of webcam. Please help

Comment: You have to UV-unwrap the faces. There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube, in case you don't know how to unwrap.